# Performance issues when handling orientation configuration change and having multiple layout resources

Tags: android, layout, onconfigurationchanged

The app I'm working on provides several layout resources for different orientation configurations: layout-land; layout-land-mdpi; layout-land-hdpi, etc.

I've noticed that the performance degrades when the platform has to choose from three alternatives - it loads the layout at average of 494 ms (from 5 attempts).

On the other hand when I define the layout only in 'res/layout' I've noticed that the performance improves and loads at average of 234.4 ms (again from 5 attempts).

In both cases there was some random GC interference for about 100-120 ms during some of the tests.

Has anyone else observed similar behaviour when you have multiple alternative layout resources for the platform to choose from? Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is the layouts being more complex?

Comment: @mobilekid: Why do you have layout resource sets by screen density? Usually layouts vary by screen size, and drawable vary by screen density. Also, you will be better served using Traceview for your performance analysis.

Comment: @Robby: the layouts are equally complex, in fact they have the same hierarchal structure and number of sub-views, the only difference is some fixed width/height values.

Comment: @CommonsWare: You're right, this is poor design, I wouldn't have done that myself... I'm just fixing the performance issues caused by someone else, and I've noticed that if I remove the alternative layouts the performance improves significantly. Thanks, I will give Traceview a go.

Comment: @mobilekid: Aha! The old "it's, um, someone else's code, honest!" line. :-) BTW, if you think of it, @ me back if you update this issue with results. I wouldn't expect the sorts of results you're seeing, but I haven't done a performance analysis of this scenario.

Comment: @CommonsWare@ It really is another person's code, the other day he used android:layout_alignParentRight in a LinearLayout wrapper :) Anyway I will play with the Traceview over the weekend and update you with my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough testing I reached the conclusion that the more alternative layout resources you provide for a certain configuration, the longer it takes for the platform to resolve the right one at runtime.

During my tests I've seen G1 freeze when it attempts to resolve a layout from three alternatives and loads in nearly 3 seconds. On the other hand when you provide a single layout for the configuration it handles it within 500 ms.